# Why can not access the uwsgi server with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE response?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I use manage.py runserver `127.0.0.1:8000`, my project run perfectly, I can access success:

```
(venv) dele-MacBook-Pro:majsbh_django ldl$ python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 30, 2020 - 20:28:19
Django version 2.2.12, using settings 'mabh_django.settings_dev'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

but when I run my django rest framework project use `uwsgi` in my Mac:

```
$ uwsgi ./mabh_django/wsgi_dev.ini
```

I can not access the `127.0.0.1:8000`, with this response: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in browser.

My `wsgi_dev.py` file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'majsbh_django.settings_dev')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My pid of the uwsgi, this means the uwsgi run success:

```
(venv) dele-MacBook-Pro:mabh_django ldl$ ps -ef | grep uwsgi
  501 24625     1   0  8:24PM ??         0:00.44 uwsgi ./mabh_django/wsgi_dev.ini
  501 24627 24625   0  8:24PM ??         0:00.00 uwsgi ./mabh_django/wsgi_dev.ini
  501 24628 24625   0  8:24PM ??         0:00.00 uwsgi ./mabh_django/wsgi_dev.ini
  501 24629 24625   0  8:24PM ??         0:00.00 uwsgi ./mabh_django/wsgi_dev.ini
  501 24630 24625   0  8:24PM ??         0:00.00 uwsgi ./mabh_django/wsgi_dev.ini
  501 24631 24625   0  8:24PM ??         0:00.00 uwsgi ./mabh_django/wsgi_dev.ini
  501 24632 24625   0  8:24PM ??         0:00.00 uwsgi ./mabh_django/wsgi_dev.ini
  501 24633 24625   0  8:24PM ??         0:00.00 uwsgi ./mabh_django/wsgi_dev.ini
  501 24634 24625   0  8:24PM ??         0:00.00 uwsgi ./mabh_django/wsgi_dev.ini
  501 24652  7943   0  8:25PM ttys007    0:00.00 grep uwsgi
```

my wsgi_dev.ini configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
uid=www
gid=www

socket = :8000
chdir = /Users/dele/Desktop/mark/mabh_django
# Django's wsgi file
wsgi-file =/Users/dele/Desktop/mark/mabh_django/mabh_django/wsgi_dev.py
processes = 8
threads = 4
pythonpath=/Users/dele/Desktop/mark/mabh_django/venv
buffer-size=65535
static-map=/Users/dele/Desktop/mark/mabh_django/static=static
vacuum = true
pidfile=uwsgi.pid
daemonize=uwsgi.daemonize.log
master=True
```

===

**EDIT-01**

```
(venv) dele-MacBook-Pro:mabh_django ldl$ more uwsgi.daemonize.log 
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Sat May 30 21:01:11 2020] ***
compiled with version: 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59) on 30 May 2020 11:52:51
os: Darwin-19.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64
nodename: aircrafts-MacBook-Pro.local
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /Users/dele/Desktop/mark/mabh_django
writing pidfile to uwsgi.pid
detected binary path: /Users/dele/Desktop/mark/mabh_django/venv/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /Users/dele/Desktop/mark/mabh_django
your processes number limit is 1392
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 10240
building mime-types dictionary from file /etc/apache2/mime.types...1003 entry found
lock engine: OSX spinlocks
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :8000 fd 3
Python version: 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25)  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
Set PythonHome to /Users/dele/Desktop/mark/mabh_django/venv/
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000011689cdc0 (most recent call first):
```